# VueJs - Trigger watch if I change an objective?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How can I let trigger watch if I change player.id? Currently it's not triggered. If I change this.player = 5 then it works, but not if I try this.player.id = 5.

My component looks currently like this:

```
<template>
    <div @click="changeVal()" class="player" :id="getId">
        {{ player.id }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Player',
        props: ['player'],
        computed: {
            getId() {
                return 'p' + this.player.id
            }
        },
        methods: {
            changeVal() {
                this.player.id = 5
            }
        },
        watch: {
            player: function(newVal, oldVal) {
                console.log('watch triggered');
            }
        },
    };
</script>
```

Comment: did you check [this](https://forum-archive.vuejs.org/topic/170/v-for-a-component) and try add `:data="player"`

Comment: **What does your component look like?** There's nothing wrong with binding a data object to a component property. Any changes to the `player` object should be reflected in the component's output

Comment: :data is creating an html data-tag, that's not what I want.

Comment: Don't try `:data`, that's not the name of the `prop` you're using

Comment: Your component should have `{{player.id}}`, **not** `{{this.player.id}}`. The template is evaluated in the scope of the component so you do not need the `this` prefix

Comment: The player-component also receive changes of the data. The object is updating, but I also wanna trigger a method in my player-component if the object is changing. Thank you Phil, I removed this.

Comment: FYI: You should not be changing properties on a `prop` object. Instead, _emit_ an event so the parent can pick it up. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your template variable is incorrect. It should be

```
<div class="player" :id="getId">{{ player.id }}</div>
```

---

To trigger a function on a data change, you can use a `watch` in your component. For example

```js
watch: {
  'player.field': function(newValue, oldValue) {
    alert(`Field changed for player ${this.player.id} from ${oldValue} to ${newValue}`)
  }
}
```

Demo ~ https://jsfiddle.net/1ajty71p/4/